# Cocos2D making a isometric hexagonal tileMap

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to create a simple game with an isometric map with Cocos2D, but I can't figure how I should use an hexagonal tile (always isometric) map.
Any hints?

Comment: This question is broad and unspecific.

Comment: you can't have a hexagonal map that's also isometric at the same time

Comment: LMAO, that's a bad new, is there no way to accomplish an isometric map that has hexagonal tile in Cocos2D? Like this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/pleasing-isometric-hexagons. I have to write all my own?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3atiled_maps) is probably your best bet for tile maps using cocos2d.  I believe that the cocos2d sample code that comes with it has a hex tile map as well.