# Cocos2d. Hexagonal map example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, hexagonal-tiles

Are there any concrete examples of code using hexagonal maps with cocos2d? Except of drawing them manually, of course.
I have found out that Tiled map editor (java version) allows to create these maps. But how to work with such map?
I also don't know how to prepare a image for drawing into a hexagonal cell

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531535/cocos2d-making-a-isometric-hexagonal-tilemap

Comment: read this "concrete examples" and "except of drawing them manually"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is to draw manually. But I have found an interesting way to store this field into an usual 2d array.
For examle:

[image]

where circles are hexagons.

I can store this map as:

0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0